# phpcs: Request workspace/configuration failed with message:unable to locate phpcs

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpcs

phpcs: Request workspace/configuration failed with message:unable to locate phpcs. please add phpcs to your global path or use composer dependency manager to install it in your project locally.

Comment: It might help if you give us some more context: what operating system, version of Visual Studio Code, and what you are trying to do when this error appears.